# How do I connect an Android app to MongoDB stitch?

Tags: android, database, mongodb, nosql

I've been following this tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-mongodb-stitch-in-android-apps--cms-31877

But I'm stuck at around steps 5 (Establish a Connection) and 6 (Insert Documents). I'm really new to Android studio and creating android apps, and the code provided really doesn't show me context on where it all needs to be placed.

I understand everything that's going on, but the tutorial seems a bit vague on where the code needs to be placed in order for the connection to be established to the database.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

this may help. it's from mongodb website (when logged in)...example snippet:

```
final StitchAppClient client =
        Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("STITCH_CLIENT_APP_ID"); // replace STITCH_CLIENT_APP_ID with App ID

final RemoteMongoClient mongoClient =
        client.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb1"); // replace mongodb1 with mongodb-atlas

final RemoteMongoCollection<Document> coll =
        mongoClient.getDatabase("<DATABASE>").getCollection("<COLLECTION>"); // replace <DATABASE> with Stitch db and <COLLECTION> with Stitch collection

client.getAuth().loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential()).continueWithTask(
        new Continuation<StitchUser, Task<RemoteUpdateResult>>() {

          @Override
          public Task<RemoteUpdateResult> then(@NonNull Task<StitchUser> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.e("STITCH", "Login failed!");
              throw task.getException();
            }

            final Document updateDoc = new Document(
                    "owner_id",
                    task.getResult().getId()
            );

            updateDoc.put("number", 42);
            return coll.updateOne(
                    null, updateDoc, new RemoteUpdateOptions().upsert(true)
            );
          }
        }
).continueWithTask(new Continuation<RemoteUpdateResult, Task<List<Document>>>() {
  @Override
  public Task<List<Document>> then(@NonNull Task<RemoteUpdateResult> task) throws Exception {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
      Log.e("STITCH", "Update failed!");
      throw task.getException();
    }
    List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
    return coll
            .find(new Document("owner_id", client.getAuth().getUser().getId()))
            .limit(100)
            .into(docs);
  }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Document>>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Document>> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      Log.d("STITCH", "Found docs: " + task.getResult().toString());
      return;
    }
    Log.e("STITCH", "Error: " + task.getException().toString());
    task.getException().printStackTrace();
  }
});
```